# Custom Spring ResourceLoader using the ClasspathXmlApplicationContext

Tags: java, spring

I am looking for a way to create custom ResourceLoader, that will use read from hbase table for the properties. I found that i can create my own ApplicationContext, override getResource and use my own ResourceLoader.

```
@Override
public Resource getResource(String location) {
    if (location.startsWith(HbaseResource.HBASE_PREFIX) ) {
        ResourceLoader loader = (ResourceLoader)getBean(HbaseResourceLoader.class);
        return loader.getResource(location);
    } else{
        return super.getResource(location);
    }
}
```

I'm looking for a way to get the same results, only using ClasspathXmlApplicationContext and not create my own contxt class.
Reading about [ResourceLoaderAware](http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/3.0.x/javadoc-api/org/springframework/context/ResourceLoaderAware.html) i see this line:

> As alternative to a ResourcePatternResolver dependency, consider
>   exposing bean properties of type Resource array, populated via pattern
>   Strings with automatic type conversion by the bean factory.

Can this help me in any way?
Is there another way i missed to register custom ResourceLoader?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

ResourceLoader is kind of a special building block and can't be directly injected like some other container services, but I believe your observation on the type conversion can help.  You can install a ConversionService (with bean name "conversionService") with some capabilities that suit you, and if you can make sure that it gets registered before any conversion needs to take place then I think it will work.  How you do that depends on whether you use XML or @Configuration probably.  A simple toy example:

```
@Test
public void testResource() {
    System.setProperty("value", "123");
    System.setProperty("resource", "location:not.found");
    AnnotationConfigApplicationContext context = new AnnotationConfigApplicationContext();
    context.register(TestConfig.class);
    context.refresh();
    Resource resource = context.getBean("resource", Resource.class);
    assertTrue(resource.exists());
}

@Configuration
@Import(ConversionConfig.class)
public static class TestConfig {

    @Value("${resource}")
    private Resource resource;

    @Bean
    public Resource resource() {
        return resource;
    }

    @Bean
    public static PropertySourcesPlaceholderConfigurer placeholders() {
        return new PropertySourcesPlaceholderConfigurer();
    }

}

@Configuration
public static class ConversionConfig {

    @Bean
    protected ConversionService conversionService(final ResourceLoader loader) {
        GenericConversionService service = new GenericConversionService();
        service.addConverter(new Converter<String, Resource>() {
            public Resource convert(String location) {
                Resource resource = loader.getResource(location);
                if (resource.exists()) {
                    return resource;
                }
                return new ByteArrayResource("foo".getBytes());
            }
        });
        return service;
    }

}
```

Comment: Some JIRA references: [SPR-3721](https://jira.springsource.org/browse/SPR-3721), [SPR-9505](https://jira.springsource.org/browse/SPR-9505).  As you can see it's something of an obsession of mine.